# trying to add upload image in my form CI MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I have form for input. Input for this form is quite complicated, because one form is submitted to more than three table in database.
 I want to add upload image in my form, but I don't know where should I put it.
 here's my ***controller*** for input

```
function c_submit(){
    $data = array(
        'no_form' => $this->input->post('noform'),
        'no_kon' => $this->input->post('nokon'),
        'tgl_kun' => $this->input->post('tk'),
        'tgl_input' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'no_lok' => $this->input->post('nolok'),
        'no_obs' => $this->input->post('noobs'),
        'no_koor' => $this->input->post('nokoor'),
        'no_lahan' => $this->input->post('nolahan'),
        't_utama' => $this->input->post('tutama'),
        'pola_t' => $this->input->post('ptanam'),
        'dlm_olah' => $this->input->post('kolah'),
        't_tanah' => $this->input->post('ttanah'),
        'no_prod' => $this->input->post('noprod'),
        'np_padi' => $this->input->post('nppadi'),
        'np_jagung' => $this->input->post('npjagung'),
        'np_kedelai' => $this->input->post('npked'),
        'np_lain' => $this->input->post('nplain'),
        'catatan' => $this->input->post('cat')
    );

    $datakon = array(
        'no_kon' => $this->input->post('nokon'),
        'jabatan' => $this->input->post('jab'),
        'nama' => $this->input->post('namakon'),
        'telp' => $this->input->post('telp')
    );

    $datakoor = array(
        'no_koor' => $this->input->post('nokoor'),
        'utm_y' => $this->input->post('y'),
        'utm_x' => $this->input->post('x')
    );

    $datalahan = array(
        'no_lahan' => $this->input->post('nolahan'),
        'jenis' => $this->input->post('jlahan'),
        'penggunaan' => $this->input->post('plahan'),
        'kondisi' => $this->input->post('klahan'),
        'drainase' => $this->input->post('drain')
    );

    $dataprod = array(
        'no_prod' => $this->input->post('noprod'),
        'p_padi' => $this->input->post('p_padi'),
        'p_jagung' => $this->input->post('p_jagung'),
        'p_kedelai' => $this->input->post('p_ked'),
        'pr_lain' => $this->input->post('pr_lain'),
        'prod_lain' => $this->input->post('prod_lain'),
        'pr_lain2' => $this->input->post('pr_lain2'),
        'prod_lain2' => $this->input->post('prod_lain2')
    );

    $datavar = array(
        'no_var' => $this->input->post('novar'),
        'v_padi' => $this->input->post('v_padi'),
        'v_jagung' => $this->input->post('v_jagung'),
        'v_kedelai' => $this->input->post('v_ked'),
        'v_lain' => $this->input->post('v_lain'),
        'var_lain' => $this->input->post('var_lain'),
        'v_lain2' => $this->input->post('v_lain2'),
        'var_lain2' => $this->input->post('var_lain2')
    );

    $datalok = array(
        'no_lok' => $this->input->post('nolok'),
        'kabu' => $this->input->post('kabu'),
        'keca' => $this->input->post('keca'),
        'desa' => $this->input->post('desa'),
        'desk' => $this->input->post('desk_lok')
    );

    $datappadi = array(
        'np_padi' => $this->input->post('nppadi'),
        'p_organik' => $this->input->post('padi_o'),
        'p_urea' => $this->input->post('padi_u'),
        'p_kcl' => $this->input->post('padi_k'),
        'p_sp36' => $this->input->post('padi_s'),
        'p_phonska' => $this->input->post('padi_p'),
        'p_lain' => $this->input->post('pp_l'),
        'pp_lain' => $this->input->post('padi_l')
    );

    $datapjagung = array(
        'np_jagung' => $this->input->post('npjagung'),
        'j_organik' => $this->input->post('jagung_o'),
        'j_urea' => $this->input->post('jagung_u'),
        'j_kcl' => $this->input->post('jagung_k'),
        'j_sp36' => $this->input->post('jagung_s'),
        'j_phonska' => $this->input->post('jagung_p'),
        'j_lain' => $this->input->post('pj_l'),
        'pj_lain' => $this->input->post('jagung_l')
    );

    $datapked = array(
        'np_kedelai' => $this->input->post('npked'),
        'k_organik' => $this->input->post('ked_o'),
        'k_urea' => $this->input->post('ked_u'),
        'k_kcl' => $this->input->post('ked_k'),
        'k_sp36' => $this->input->post('ked_s'),
        'k_phonska' => $this->input->post('ked_p'),
        'k_lain' => $this->input->post('pk_l'),
        'pk_lain' => $this->input->post('ked_l')
    );

    $dataplain = array(
        'np_lain' => $this->input->post('nplain'),
        'jenis_l' => $this->input->post('j_lain'),
        'organik' => $this->input->post('lain_o'),
        'urea' => $this->input->post('lain_u'),
        'kcl' => $this->input->post('lain_k'),
        'sp36' => $this->input->post('lain_s'),
        'phonska' => $this->input->post('lain_p'),
        'pupuk_lain' => $this->input->post('pl_l'),
        'pem_lain' => $this->input->post('lain_l')
    );

    $no_obs = $this->session->userdata('no_obs');
    $this->m_input->m_submit($data, $datakon, $datakoor, $datalahan, $dataprod, $datavar, $datalok, $datappadi, $datapjagung, $datapked, $dataplain);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success"><p><b>SUKSES!</b> Data berhasil diinputkan!</p></div>');
    redirect('c_read');

}
```

and this my ***model***

```
function m_submit($data, $datakon, $datakoor, $datalahan, $dataprod, $datavar, $datalok, $datappadi, $datapjagung, $datapked, $dataplain) {

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->insert('koor_pen', $datakoor); 
    $no_koor = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    $this->db->insert('kontak', $datakon); 
    $no_kon = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    $this->db->insert('lahan', $datalahan); 
    $no_lahan = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('produktivitas', $dataprod); 
    $no_prod = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('varietas', $datavar); 
    $no_var = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('lokasi', $datalok); 
    $no_lok = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_padi', $datappadi); 
    $np_padi = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_jagung', $datapjagung); 
    $np_jagung = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_kedelai', $datapked); 
    $np_kedelai = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_lain', $dataplain); 
    $np_lain = $this->db->insert_id();

    $data['no_kon'] = $no_kon;
    $data['no_koor'] = $no_koor;
    $data['no_lahan'] = $no_lahan;
    $data['no_prod'] = $no_prod;
    $data['no_var'] = $no_var;
    $data['no_lok'] = $no_lok;
    $data['np_padi'] = $np_padi;
    $data['np_jagung'] = $np_jagung;
    $data['np_kedelai'] = $np_kedelai;
    $data['np_lain'] = $np_lain;
    $this->db->insert('input_pen', $data);

    $this->db->trans_complete(); 

    return $this->db->insert_id(); 

}
```

Link for my uploaded image should in `$data` array.
 I don't know what should I do. Can anyone give me examples?

Comment: woooow what a dirty code you can do in better way

Comment: really? what should i do? i think thats not dirty code, the data is a lot

Comment: Do you want the file image to be uploaded to DB or uploaded and moved to a file, then pass path or image name to db?

Comment: the second one, uploaded and pass path or image name to db

Answer (score 0):

This script will upload your file in destination folder `mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);`

Param number 3, TRUE will create recursively the directory for you.

And the corresponding line will place a name and path to database

```
$post_data = array(
'name' => $_FILES["__INPUT__FIELD__NAME"]['name'],
'path' => $hook
);
$this->db->insert('FILES__DB__', $post_data);
```

> Generall usage

**File_handler model**

```
<?PHP

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class File_handler extends CI_Model {

    private $base_p = "./files/";
    private $ext = 'pdf|csv|doc|txt';
    private $size = 5000000;


    function _push_file($path, $name) {
        // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
        if (is_file($path)) {
            // required for IE
            if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
                ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
            }

            // get the file mime type using the file extension
            $this->load->helper('file');

            $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);

            // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
            header('Pragma: public');     // required
            header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
            header('Cache-Control: private', false);
            header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($name) . '"');  // Add the file name
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path)); // provide file size
            header('Connection: close');
            readfile($path); // push it out
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function fsize($s) {
        $this->size = $s;
    }

    public function fext($ext) {
        $this->ext = $ext;
    }

    public function upload_file($field, $subpath) {
        if (!empty($_FILES[$field]['name'])) {
            $config['upload_path'] = $this->base_p . '' . $subpath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = $this->ext;
            $config['max_size'] = $this->size; // 5 mb
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
            if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
                mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
            }
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
                $status = 'error';
                $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
                return json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'msg' => $msg));
                die();
            } else {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
            }
            return $path = 'files' . $subpath . '/' . $data['file_name'];
        }
    }

}
```

**Use this in your logic model**

```
  $this->load->model("File_handler", "fh");
                        $this->fh->fext("jpg|jpeg|pdf|png");
                        $hook = $this->fh->upload_file("__INPUT__FIELD__NAME", "__PATH__TO__UPLOAD");
                        // Errors from File_handler controller
                        if (isset(json_decode($hook)->result) && json_decode($hook)->result == "error") {
                            $message = json_decode($hook)->msg;
                        }
                        // If we got the path all is ok
                        if ($hook) {
                            $post_data = array(
                                'name' => $_FILES["__INPUT__FIELD__NAME"]['name'],
                                'path' => $hook
                            );
                            $this->db->insert('FILES__DB__', $post_data);
                            $fid = $this->db->insert_id();

                            if (!is_numeric($fid)) {
                                $message = "Error, file not added";
                            }
                        }
                if (strlen($message) == 0) {
                    // No errors in the file handler
                   // get your upload url path with file name from $hook
                }else{
                  echo $message;
                }.
```

> In your case :

You will need to create a table in your database use this schema

```
CREATE TABLE `file_uploads` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `path` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes 
--
ALTER TABLE `file_uploads`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT 
--
ALTER TABLE `file_uploads`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

**Your model**

```
function m_submit($data, $datakon, $datakoor, $datalahan, $dataprod, $datavar, $datalok, $datappadi, $datapjagung, $datapked, $dataplain) {

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->insert('koor_pen', $datakoor);
    $no_koor = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('kontak', $datakon);
    $no_kon = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('lahan', $datalahan);
    $no_lahan = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('produktivitas', $dataprod);
    $no_prod = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('varietas', $datavar);
    $no_var = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('lokasi', $datalok);
    $no_lok = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_padi', $datappadi);
    $np_padi = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_jagung', $datapjagung);
    $np_jagung = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_kedelai', $datapked);
    $np_kedelai = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('pem_lain', $dataplain);
    $np_lain = $this->db->insert_id();

    $data['no_kon'] = $no_kon;
    $data['no_koor'] = $no_koor;
    $data['no_lahan'] = $no_lahan;
    $data['no_prod'] = $no_prod;
    $data['no_var'] = $no_var;
    $data['no_lok'] = $no_lok;
    $data['np_padi'] = $np_padi;
    $data['np_jagung'] = $np_jagung;
    $data['np_kedelai'] = $np_kedelai;
    $data['np_lain'] = $np_lain;
    $this->db->insert('input_pen', $data);

    /* add my image */
    $this->load->model("File_handler", "fh");
    $this->fh->fext("jpg|jpeg|pdf|png");
    $hook = $this->fh->upload_file("__INPUT__FIELD__NAME", "__PATH__TO__UPLOAD");
    // Errors from File_handler controller
    if (isset(json_decode($hook)->result) && json_decode($hook)->result == "error") {
        $message = json_decode($hook)->msg;
    }
    // If we got the path all is ok
    if ($hook) {
        $post_data = array(
            'name' => $_FILES["foto"]['name'],
            'path' => $hook
        );
        $this->db->insert('file_uploads', $post_data);
        $fid = $this->db->insert_id();

        if (!is_numeric($fid)) {
            $message = "Error, file not added";
        }
    }
    if (strlen($message) == 0) {
    // No errors in the file handler

    // get your upload url path with file name from $hook and do here whatever u want

    } else {
        echo $message;
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**Things to be noticed HTML**

You need to have your form enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form id="FormId" name="Formname" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

And the input type file

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="foto" id="foto">
```

**Code sample for jquery ajax handling**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>CONTROLLER/FUNCTION',
    type: "POST",
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        // Your logic
    }
});
```

Comment: If you give me your field name of the image I can do so

Comment: field name of the image is "foto" and that sould be in $data array

Comment: @Kiki check this out

Comment: success input but nothing inputed to table upload_file

Answer (score 0):

First lets clear the code

for submit sevral forms you can easily user array in html name tag

```
<input name="datakon[no_kon]" >
<input name="datakon[jab]" >
<input name="datakon[namakon]" >
<input name="datakon[telp]" >
```

And in Controller side you insert  them into database in one line

```
$datakon = $this->input->post('datakon');
$this->db->insert('kontak', $datakon); 
$no_kon = $this->db->insert_id();
```

And if your database table name was same as your input fields, its done

Now lets to start uploading files

> You should not Upload files in database.

instead of uploading file to database you can uplade files to a directory and save that directory address.

for uploading files you can use codeigniter upload library [Codeigniter Upload File Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

```
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('no_kon'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
```

Hope to help

Comment: actually my form didn't just insert into "kontak" table, but insert into all table like my code above

Comment: yea i already read that documentation, but still i didn't know where to start. can you help me

Comment: In else block, before loading the view.